# Poincaré series of deloopings of finite complexes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, power-series

Recall that the Poincaré series of a topological space $X$ is defined as $P_X(t) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} b_jt^j$, where $b_j = \text{dim}_{\mathbb Q} H_{j}(X;\mathbb Q)$ means the $j^{\text{th}}$ (rational) Betti number of $X$.

Suppose $X$ is such that the loop space $\Omega X$ has the homotopy type of a finite CW-complex. Does this imply that $P_X(t)$ is a rational function? If not, what are examples of $X$ so that this fails?

Comment: When $\Omega X$ is connected, I understand that $H^*(X;\mathbb Q)$ is in fact a polynomial algebra on finitely many generators. See bottom of page 2 in the paper of Andersen-Bauer-Grodal-Pedersen. For more general $X$, it would be the invariants of the action of a finite group on a polynomial algebra, so I would think the Poincare series would be a rational function for general reasons of invariant theory. Am I missing something?

Comment: That sounds great, thanks; if you make your comment into an answer I would accept it.